# Gmail API batch request limit

Tags: gmail-api

What's the actual limit for number of api calls in a single batch request? The documentation says it's 100 (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch#overview) but I've been able to make 2000 in a single request reducing the overall time. It's there actually a limit on the number or the limit is imposed by the size of the response?

Comment: Did all of them process though? Probably not. Otherwise their service is faulty or documentation out of date. Might be a good idea sending their support an email.

Comment: All of them were processed with no errors

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, the documented limit is 100.

Larger batch requests *may* work, but are not guaranteed to work.  This means that larger requests may stop working at some point, or work "sometimes".

Also note that the batched items count individually toward your rate limit.  From the same page:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch#overview

> Note: A set of n requests batched together counts toward your usage
>   limit as n requests, not as one request. The batch request is taken
>   apart into a set of requests before processing.

See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota  Note that this page suggests keeping batches smaller than 50 to avoid triggering usage limits.